# How to check whether a Windows user has admin privileges in C?

Tags: c, windows, if-statement

Is there any way of conditionally checking (strictly in C) whether a Windows user has administrator privileges or not?

I wish to do this programmatically (not simply telling the user to "Run as Administrator").

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of fundamentally different ways. The most common 
is, unfortunately, rather tedious. It involves finding the current 
user's SID, then finding the groups to which he belongs, and then 
finding whether one of them is the Administrators group:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <vector>

bool is_administrator() { 
    HANDLE access_token; 
    DWORD buffer_size = 0; 
    PSID admin_SID; 
    TOKEN_GROUPS *group_token = NULL; 
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NT_authority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY; 

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),TOKEN_READ,&access_token)) 
        return false; 

    GetTokenInformation( 
        access_token, 
        TokenGroups, 
        group_token, 
        0, 
        &buffer_size 
        ); 

    std::vector<char> buffer(buffer_size);

    group_token = 
        reinterpret_cast<TOKEN_GROUPS*>(&buffer[0]); 

    bool succeeded = GetTokenInformation( 
        access_token, 
        TokenGroups, 
        group_token, 
        buffer_size, 
        &buffer_size 
        ); 

    CloseHandle(access_token); 
    if (!succeeded) 
        return false;

    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid( 
        &NT_authority, 
        2, 
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, 
        DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 
        0,0,0,0,0,0, 
        &admin_SID 
        )) 
    {
        return false; 
    }

    bool found=false; 
    for(int i=0; !found && i < group_token->GroupCount; i++) 
        found = EqualSid(admin_SID,group_token->Groups[i].Sid); 
    FreeSid(admin_SID); 
    return found; 
}
```

There's another way that's a bit simpler though:

```
bool is_administrator() 
{ 
        bool result; 
        DWORD rc; 
        wchar_t user_name[256]; 
        USER_INFO_1 *info; 
        DWORD size = sizeof( user_name ); 
        GetUserNameW( user_name, &size); 
        rc = NetUserGetInfo( NULL, user_name, 1, (byte **) &info ); 
        if ( rc != NERR_Success ) 
                return false; 
        result = info->usri1_priv == USER_PRIV_ADMIN; 
        NetApiBufferFree( info ); 
        return result; 
}
```

In either case, if you have a domain, things can be a little hairy, 
because a particular user might be an administrator on the local 
machine, but not on the domain, or vice versa. Finding the info 
doesn't necessarily change much, but you may have to think a bit to 
figure out what you really want.

Edit: As @Benj pointed out, the first method could really use a bit of updating. While I already fixed the obvious leak it had, it's still a huge, monolithic function with no exception safety, and generally rather outdated coding style. Perhaps a small update is in order:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class sid {
    PSID s;
public:
    sid(SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY auth, std::vector<DWORD> sub_auths) {
        DWORD count = sub_auths.size();
        sub_auths.resize(7, DWORD());

        if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid( 
            &auth,
            count, 
            sub_auths[0], sub_auths[1], sub_auths[2], sub_auths[3],
            sub_auths[4], sub_auths[5], sub_auths[6], sub_auths[7],
            &s 
            )) 
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to allocate Admin SID");
        }
    }

    sid(PSID const &p=NULL) : s(p) {}
    bool operator==(sid const &r) const { return EqualSid(s, r.s); }
};

class access_token {
    HANDLE token;
public:
    access_token(HANDLE PID=GetCurrentProcess(), DWORD access=TOKEN_READ) {
        if (!OpenProcessToken(PID, access, &token))
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to open process token");
    }
    operator HANDLE() { return token; }
    ~access_token() { CloseHandle(token); }
};

std::vector<sid> get_group_sids() {
    DWORD buffer_size = 0; 
    TOKEN_GROUPS *group_token = NULL; 
    std::vector<sid> groups;
    access_token token;

    GetTokenInformation(token, TokenGroups, group_token, 0, &buffer_size);

    std::vector<char> buffer(buffer_size);

    group_token = reinterpret_cast<TOKEN_GROUPS*>(&buffer[0]);

    if (GetTokenInformation(token, TokenGroups, group_token, buffer_size, &buffer_size))
        for (int i=0; i<group_token->GroupCount; i++)
            groups.push_back(group_token->Groups[i].Sid);
    return groups;
}

bool is_administrator() {
    std::vector<sid> groups = get_group_sids();

    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NT_authority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    std::vector<DWORD> sub_auths;

    sub_auths.push_back(SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID);
    sub_auths.push_back(DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS);

    sid admin_SID(NT_authority, sub_auths);

    return std::find(groups.begin(), groups.end(), admin_SID) != groups.end();
}

#ifdef TEST
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_administrator() << "\n";
}

#endif
```

Comment: In the first example, where does the `new char[buffer_size]` get deleted?

Comment: Could always give it a quick mod to a `vector<char>`

Comment: @Benj: You should held out for the third version! :-)

Comment: Sorry Jerry, +1 is my limit ;-)

Comment: It is worth to note that different methods can have different outcome. For example, if `foobar` is logged-in, and you remove `foobar` from Administrators group via `net localgroup Administrators foobar /Delete`, the first method (`OpenProcessToken`) will claim that `foobar` is Admin, while the second method will not. I find the first method more preferable because it is consistent with the fact that `foobar` still have admin power until it logs off.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly different (and shorter? easier?) method adapted from some hints on MSDN:

```
PSID administrators_group = NULL;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY nt_authority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
BOOL result = AllocateAndInitializeSid( &nt_authority, 2, SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &administrators_group);
BOOL is_user_admin = FALSE;
if (result)
{
    CheckTokenMembership(NULL, administrators_group, &is_user_admin);
    FreeSid(administrators_group);
}

if (is_user_admin)
{
    // do something here for admin users...
}
```

Comment: I have not tested, but wonder if you know whether this will work with UAC-enabled machines, to determine UAC elevation, not necessarily membership to an Administrator group?

Answer (score 3):

Sure you need to call:

```
OpenThreadToken()
```

To get the user's token.

```
GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenGroups, NULL, 0, &dwNeeded)
```

To get the size of the token group information (and allocate enough space)

```
GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenGroups, pTokenGroups, dwSize, &dwNeeded)
```

To get the local groups

```
AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthNT, 2, SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &psidAdministrators);
```

To get the SID of the Administrator

```
EqualSid()
```

To compare that SID with the SIDs in your local groups.

Comment: Thanks, This helped me but at first I didn't realize that it is ok that the first call to GetTokenInformation was returning an error. I suggest adding into the answer (make sure GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY).

Comment: This is actually a really common pattern in Win32 programming.  Whenever you see an API getting called twice, the first time with NULL it's usually the case that the first call is getting the size so that you can allocate the right memory for the second call.